# Cartographic numbering of points on map

Tags: cartography, references

Usually when I create maps with a set of numbered points (e.g. numbered locations on the map which link across to a separate table describing these points) I try to number them in a rough "reading order". I.e. in more-or-less horizontal strips from left to right, beginning at the top of the page.

I've started wondering lately if this is the best approach, but am unable to find any guidelines or research on what is the most ideal numbering sequence for maps.

So now I'm seeking any best-practice guides or publications discussing this. (Obviously the main guiding factor here is aiding map readers to quickly locate a specific numbered point on the map itself!)

Comment: Reading order is the most logical for western readers (unlike arabic right to left) like this map? https://easthamchamber.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/roadmap.pdf vs https://www.eremnews.com/news/arab-world/36438

Comment: Depends on underlying features, e.g. points on streams need to follow flow direction.

Comment: A screen shot of your typical data and labelling would be helpful?